# «Крест», народное название перекрестка улиц. Пишется с большой или с маленькой буквы?

Tags: выбор-слов

«Крест» – это просторечное название перекрестка двух улиц в столице Крыма. Пишется с большой или с маленькой буквы?

Comment: Просторечные названия не пишутся, а употребляются в устной речи (почему и называются просторечными). Если это один определённый перекрёсток - то пишется с заглавной буквы. Если у них так называют перекрёстки вообще - организовать там курсы правильного русского языка ))

Comment: определенный перекресток....

Comment: он только один)))

Answer (score 1):

С прописной буквы, как и любое имя собственное - хошь народное, хошь литературное.

Прецедент всем известен - питерские Пять углов, но такие названия есть и в других городах.

Есть книга «У Пяти углов» автора Михаил Чулаки...

> Площадь Пять углов – это необычная достопримечательность в
>   Санкт-Петербурге - ее название отсутствует на городских картах, но
>   именно здесь, на пересечении Загородного проспекта, улиц Рубинштейна,
>   Ломоносова и Разъезжей, можно почувствовать дух Петербурга.

**[Пять углов в других городах](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C_%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2_(%D0%A1%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%82-%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B3)#.D0.9B.D0.B8.D1.82.D0.B5.D1.80.D0.B0.D1.82.D1.83.D1.80.D0.B0)** (цитирую только три, но по ссылке их с десяток):

> - В Великом Новгороде пересечение улиц Большой Санкт-Петербургской, Предтеченской и Козьмодемьянской носит неофициальное название «Пять
>     углов».
> - В Мурманске в самом центре города есть площадь Пяти Углов, которая раньше называлась площадью Советской Конституции. На ней находится
>     гостиница «Арктика», а неподалёку — железнодорожный вокзал.
> - В Москве неофициальное название «Пять углов» носит Лялина площадь, расположенная на стыке переулков: Лялина, Барашевского, Большого
>     Казённого и Малого Казённого.

Answer (score 1):

***Крест*** - перекресток улиц Пушкина и Карла Маркса в городе Симферополе.
[**Пуп земли**](http://rolewiki.org/%D0%9A%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82)

"Нахаловка", "Пьяный угол", ***"Крест"***: загадки названий симферопольских микрорайонов.
[**Симферополь**](http://crimea.vgorode.ua/news/dosuh_y_eda/147784/)

Улица Пушкина, встречаясь с улицей Карла Маркса, образует перекресток. Горожане называют его ***"крест"***.
[**Перекресток**](http://www.vkrim.info/catalog/venue/6819)

Как менялась жизнь на ***«кресте»*** за последние 100 лет...
[**Встретимся на «кресте»**](http://crimea.rusplt.ru/index/Istoriya-samogo-izvestnogo-perekryostka-v-Simferopole-11403.html)

Да, действительно, *он такой один!* А вот "обозначений" - несколько.
Я бы здесь провела аналогию с Санкт-Петербургскими "Крестами" - они тоже единственные в своем роде, никто не перепутает.

**"Крест"** - думаю, так будет правильно - имя собственное, с заглавной, но в кавычках. Ведь креста-то, как такового, там нет.